# 16-bit value becomes negative when bit shifting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am seeing some odd behaviour when I try to bit shift a 16-bit value

```
0xF << 4 == 0xF0 // true

0xFF << 8 == 0xFF00 // true

0xFFF << 12 == 0xFFF000 // true

0xFFFF << 16 == 0xFFFF0000 // false
```

The reason the last one is true is that `0xFFFF << 16` actually gives the value `-65536`. Why is this happening when `0xFFFF0000` is a valid number in JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Javascript uses [signed 32-bit integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers) numbers for bitwise operations.

That means, the numbers can be negative.

To have your desired output, you have to remove the sign with `>>> 0`.

```
(0xFFFF << 16) >>> 0 == 0xFFFF0000
```

Comment: Thanks. I can get the output I want with `(0xFFFF << 16) >>> 0`